# Using jcifs in jython in order to access site using NTLM security

Tags: java, python, jython, ntlm, jcifs

For a while now I have been trying to find a way for jython to access site using NTLM. I have just basic knowledge of python and next to none in java, so I could use some help (or an example) how to make the request use NTLM in this script part I have found. I am using this with open source application grinder.

First I start with importing jcifs in script along with others used by grinder:

```
from net.grinder.script import Test
from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder
from net.grinder.plugin.http import HTTPPluginControl, HTTPRequest
from HTTPClient import NVPair

from jcifs.ntlmssp import Type1Message
from jcifs.ntlmssp import Type2Message, Type3Message
from jcifs.util import Base64
```

This code part was provided in example I found. It was the closes thing I could find, that would fit my needs, since I just need to get the full response to request.

```
def NTLMAuthentication1(url, request, info, NTLMfield):
    token_type1 = info.token_type1()

    params = (NVPair("Authorization", "NTLM "+token_type1), )
    result = request.GET(url, None, params)
    NTLMfield = result.getHeader("WWW-Authenticate")
    return NTLMAuthentication2(url, request, info, NTLMfield)

def NTLMAuthentication2(url, request, info, NTLMfield):
    if NTLMfield.startswith("Negotiate"):
        token_type2 = NTLMfield[len("Negotiate "):]
    else:
        token_type2 = NTLMfield[5:]

    token_type3 = info.token_type3(token_type2)
    params = (NVPair("Cookie", "WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated=80"),
              NVPair("Authorization", "NTLM " + token_type3), )
    result = request.GET(url, None, params)
    return result

# this function validate request and its result to see if the NTLM authentication is required
def NTLMAuthentication(lastResult, request, info):
    # get last http request's url
    url = lastResult.getEffectiveURI().toString()[len(request.getUrl()):]

    # The result is ask for authentication
    if lastResult.statusCode != 401 and lastResult.statusCode != 407:
        return lastResult

    NTLMfield = lastResult.getHeader("WWW-Authenticate")
    if NTLMfield == None:
        return lastResult

    # check it is the first shakehands
    if NTLMfield == "Negotiate, NTLM" or NTLMfield == "NTLM":
        return NTLMAuthentication1(url, request, info, NTLMfield)

    # check it is the second shakehands
    elif len(NTLMfield) > 4 and NTLMfield[:4] == "NTLM":
        return NTLMAuthentication2(url, request, info, NTLMfield)

    else:
        return lastResult

class NTLMAuthenticationInfo:
    def __init__(self, domain, host, user, passwd):
        self.domain = 'domain'
        self.host = 'host'
        self.user = 'user'
        self.passwd = 'password' 

    def token_type1(self):
        msg = Type1Message(Type1Message.getDefaultFlags(), self.domain, self.host)
        return Base64.encode(msg.toByteArray())

    def token_type3(self, token_type2):
        msg2 = Type2Message(Base64.decode(token_type2))

#if jcifs 1.3.7 using msg3 = Type3Message(msg2, self.passwd, self.domain, self.user, self.host)
        msg3 = Type3Message(msg2, self.passwd, self.domain, self.user, self.host)
        return Base64.encode(msg3.toByteArray())
```

In the main part the request looks something like this:

```
result = request101.GET('/')
```

where request101 has been predefined with URL and header. So, basically, I don't have a clue how to implement the

I have tried this

```
result = request101.GET('/')
print str(NTLMAuthentication(result, request101, NTLMAuthenticationInfo))
```

as well as just this

```
 NTLMAuthentication(request101.GET('/'), request101, NTLMAuthenticationInfo)
```

but neither of these worked. Any tips on how to run this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ai = NTLMAuthenticationInfo("domain", "your host", "user", "password")
result = request101.GET('/')
result = NTLMAuthentication(result, request101, ai)
```